# how can i sleep code without freezing the UI?

Tags: java, javafx

So, i'm working on a javafx application and i'm trying to switch between scenes, Scene 1 and Scene 2, but there are a "loading" scene in the middle of both. I'm trying to use `Thread.sleep()` to simulate the loading screen animation before switch to the Scene 2, but the animation freezes (and yeah, i know it's because that Thread is the "UI Thread").

I've tried with a timeline but doesn't work, i'm pretty new and i'm probably doing something wrong lol

What can i do? looking for something simple.

My code:

```
private void handleButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        if(true){
            Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
            Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoadingFXML.fxml"));
            Scene loading= new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(loading);
            stage.show();
            
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
               public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                  System.out.println("Waiting");
                }
            }));
            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
            timeline.play();

            root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene2FXML.fxml"));
            Scene scene2=new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene2);
            stage.show();
           
        }
    }
```

FIXED:

```
private void handleButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        if(true){
            Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
            Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoadingFXML.fxml"));
            Scene loading= new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(loading);
            stage.show();
            root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene2FXML.fxml"));
            Scene scene2=new Scene(root);
            
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
               public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                  stage.setScene(scene2);
                  stage.show();;
                }
            }));
            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
            timeline.play();

            
            
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: @tevemadar yeah, i've tried with that but seems not to work becase the loading scene just appears for a second and then switch, and if i close the windows the program still running so seems to create a new thread that are sleeping but idk :(

Comment: "I tried with a `Timeline` but I'm probably doing something wrong.". Obviously you are doing something wrong, if it's not working the way you want. No one can tell you what that is, because you haven't posted your attempt to use the `Timeline`, which you clearly already know is the correct approach.

Comment: You are very close.  Move `stage.setScene(scene2);` into your EventHandler.  (Obviously that means you need load Scene2FXML.fxml and create `scene2` before creating the timeline.)

Comment: @James_D just added the code that i tried for the ´Timeline´, it does the same as the answer above "seems not to work becase the loading scene just appears for a second and then switch, and if i close the windows the program still running so seems to create a new thread that are sleeping"

Comment: @jonathanmarq you’re supposed to put the code you want to execute later in the event handler for the key frame

Comment: thanks to James_D and VGR i've find how to make it work! just one more question, there are gonna be some thouble when in the Scene2 controller if i need to get the scene from this stage? i don't think so but would be great if you can answer. Thank you, one more time.

Comment: If you've fixed this, then you should put the fix into an answer, then accept it.

Comment: i've already aded the code fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleButton()` method runs in the main thread, that is being used for UI interface drawing and reacting to the user actions.

Run this method contents in a different thread. In this case, if you call `sleep()`, it won't freeze the UI interface.

Comment: Hi @Rafael Osipov, next time please provide a short example if possible.